# Regular expression for 10 or 13 digits

Tags: regex

I tried this, but in this case, 11 and 12 are allowed too:

```
^[0-9]{10,13}$
```

I need just 10 or 13.

Comment: I've fixed a couple of typos in your question. Please review my edit to make sure I didn't change your intended meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use alternation (matches the regex before or after):

```
^[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{13}$
```

This would match 10 or 13 digits.

Answer (score 6):

You can do also

```
^\d{10}(\d{3})?$
```

10 digits + optional 3 digits